# How to Auto Restart PM2 if there is sequelize connection timeout?

Tags: express, sequelize.js, pm2

I am having issue with connection timeout, when there is sequelize connection timeout, PM2 didn't restart and when I check from PM2 list, it is still running for my backend side.
How do I make sure that PM2 can restart if there is sequelize connection error? Because pm2 is still online but I get 504 gateway timeout.